# How to handle Exceptions and ordering in AsyncIO

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Currently Im trying to process list of messages in the same order they arrive.  To process it, I'm using python asyncio to execute each message as couroutine/task. So I will be creating the couroutine/task accordingly and I will add to asyncio run forever loop. but In case of corner cases where there can be some exception occur in the coroutine. At the time of exception, I planning to retry those message or handle it differently. but the next couroutine should not be invoked to preserver the order of execution.

Is there any way to handle this ?

```
from asyncio import get_event_loop, sleep

status = True


async def c(id, sleep_time=2, fail=False):
    global status
    print(f'started the edge side {id}')
    if status:
        print('c', sleep_time, fail)
        await sleep(sleep_time)
        if fail:
            status = False
            raise Exception('fail')
        


loop = get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(c(1, sleep_time=1, fail=False))
loop.create_task(c(2, sleep_time=1, fail=False))
loop.create_task(c(3, sleep_time=1, fail=True))
loop.create_task(c(4, sleep_time=1, fail=False))
loop.create_task(c(5, sleep_time=1, fail=False))
loop.run_forever()
```

small example that I have tried and still it not working as expected... can anyone please suggest, is there any possible way to handle this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> but the next couroutine should not be invoked to preserver the order
> of execution

It sounds like you need a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) and push an item into the queue when the previous one is completed but then all messages will be processed sequentially.

The doc for [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) says:

> Wrap the coro coroutine into a Task and **schedule its execution**. Return
> the Task object.

You can see this in the following example. All task has been scheduled and when the task no. `3` failed, the remaining ones are not done but those that take less time are already completed because they were already scheduled:

```
$ python test.py
START: 1
START: 2
START: 3
START: 4
START: 5
END: 1
END: 2
END: 4
DONE: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
PENDING: ['5']
Task: 3 failed (ERROR), re-scheduling...
```

**test.py:**

```
import asyncio


async def worker(i, sleep):
    print(f"START: {i}")

    await asyncio.sleep(sleep)

    if i == 3:
        raise Exception("ERROR")

    print(f"END: {i}")


async def main():
    tasks = []

    for i in range(1, 6):
        sleep = 4 if i == 3 else i

        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(worker(i, sleep), name=i))

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)

    print(f"DONE: {sorted(t.get_name() for t in done)}")
    print(f"PENDING: {sorted(t.get_name() for t  in pending)}")

    for task in done:
        if task.exception():
            print(
                f"Task: {task.get_name()} failed ({task.exception()}), re-scheduling..."
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```